# how to find out the number of visted users sigle/multiple times to a application using sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

we need to find out the visitors to the application in a particular month, for example, JAN 2017.
We are using this query:

```
SELECT username Usuario_Oracle, COUNT (username) Numero_Sesiones
FROM v$session
where LOGON_TIME BETWEEN to_date('01-NOV-16', 'dd-mon-yy') AND to_date('30-NOV-16', 'dd-mon-yy')
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY Numero_Sesiones DESC;
```

But its not giving the desired output.

Comment: What output are you expecting to see? Have you looked at the data that's actually in the `v$session` view?

Comment: we need  to find out the  number of active users who have visited single or multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

[The `v$session` view](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9.htm) shows "information for each **current** session". You can sometimes see some recent activity (killed sessions, for instance) but you can't use it to look for historical data.

Oracle has [auditing tools](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm) if you want to track things at database level. If you specifically want to track application usage then arguably that's something your application should do itself.

If neither mechanism was enabled in January (or Novemeber) then no data is recorded anywhere so there is nothing for you to look at, unfortunately. It *may* be worth talking to your DBA to see what audit infirmation is avaialble though.